# .Net Syntax - what does "=>" do when filtering text within a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, where-clause

Say I have a collection that I want to filter on...

```
 var users = groupInner.GetMembers(true).Where(user => user.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith("D0") == false && 
     user.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith("D1") == false &&
     user.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith("D2") == false &&
     user.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith("D3") == false &&
     user.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith("D4") == false).ToList();
```

When filtering with the where clause on text, I can only get the statement to work with `=>`.  `==` doesn't seem to work.  I've tested it, the above code gives me my correct answer, but just for understanding and to find out if I should using something more appropriate than what I already have...what does `=>` mean when comparing text and is there something I should be using instead?

Comment: That creates a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Comment: [All about Lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the syntax for indicating a lambda expression.  It's called the "lambda operator".  See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

> To create a lambda expression, you specify input parameters (if any) on the left side of the lambda operator =>, and you put the expression or statement block on the other side.